# Cant work with routers

Tags: node.js, express

I set a router in app.js but its not working.

request : /user

app.js

```
var user = require('./routers/user')
app.use('/user', user)
```

user.js

```
module.exports=function(user){   
    var express = require('express')
    var router = express.Router()

    // define the home page route
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Users home page')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exporting `router` as function. Try this, it will work:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Users home page')
});

module.exports = router
```